# Запуск react без сервера nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Не понимаю, как использовать проекты на react с php.
Вот есть демо приложение, написанное на react
https://github.com/unbugx/react-demo
Запускаю сервер - всё работает.
Выключаю, открываю index.html в браузере - только h1 отображается

Comment: А в чём проблема с php? На сервере должен быть некий bundle.js, в котором будет логика приложения. В приложении, что Вы упомянули имеется скрипт `npm run deploy`. Попробуйте запустить его и посмотреть создадутся ли продакшн файлы для приложения. Тогда можно будет открыть приложение локально.

Comment: Уточните — вы хотите php сервить статику?
Или вы хотите ssr с реактом? https://vimeo.com/188948944
доклад на эту тему.

Answer (score 1):

Просто собери проект с помощью webpack'а в один js файл и подключи его, `npm run build`.